# Python Django: Add a new file in existing ZIP file and Download it

Tags: python, django, zip

I have a Zip file on server which users will download. When users will click download, a file should be generated dynamically and added to that zip, then that zip should be downloaded.

1. I know how to create zip files dynamically. But here I need to point to an existing zip and download it.
2. Second requirement of adding a new file to Zip is optional, but will be nice if it is possible. I tried opening Zip in 'a' mode, but it creates a new zip file which has the zip and new file. So a zip inside a zip which is not required.

Comment: Create a temp zip file copied from the original. Add your dynamic file to that zip and send to client. After sending delete that temp file. Write a shell script to create the temp file invoke it from python and delete the same from Python.

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote so far ?